# Error while working on JDBC Programming

Tags: java, jdbc, dao

I was working on my project, and while I was doing so, I've encountered some errors on my project. I am in the middle of creating a data access object, and here are the list of methods that I am working on.

```
public class OrderDAO {

    public void add(OrderInfo o){
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        String q = "insert into OrderInfo values (oseq.nextval, ?, ?, ?)";

        try {
            con = DBUtil.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(q);

            ps.setInt(1, o.getCnum());
            ps.setInt(2, o.getPnum());
            ps.setInt(3, o.getQuant());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("OrderInfo Registration Success");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("OrderInfo Registration fail");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            DBUtil.close(ps);
            DBUtil.close(con);
        }
    }
    public ArrayList<OrderInfo> search(){
        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        ArrayList<OrderInfo> orderInfoList = new ArrayList<>(); 

        String q = "Select onum, cnum, pnum, quant"
                + " from OrderInfo";
        try {
            con = DBUtil.getConnection();
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(q);
            while (rs.next()) {
                OrderInfo orderInfo = new OrderInfo(rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2),
                        rs.getInt(3), rs.getInt(4));
                orderInfoList.add(orderInfo);
            } // end of while

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to search");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            DBUtil.close(rs);
            DBUtil.close(st);
            DBUtil.close(con);
        }
        return orderInfoList;
    }
    public OrderInfo search(int onum){
        OrderInfo orderInfo = null;
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String q = "Select onum, cnum, pnum, quant "
                + " from OrderInfo where onum = ?";
        try {
            con = DBUtil.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(q);

            ps.setInt(1, onum);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                orderInfo = new OrderInfo(rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2), rs.getInt(3),
                        rs.getInt(4));
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Search Fail");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            DBUtil.close(rs);
            DBUtil.close(ps);
            DBUtil.close(con);
        }
        return orderInfo;
    }
    public DeliveryInfo deliverySearch(int onum){
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        DeliveryInfo di = null;
        String q = "select onum, cnum, cname, caddress, quant "
                + " from orderinfo o, customer c "
                + " where o.onum = c.cnum and onum = ?";
        try {
            con = DBUtil.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(q);
            ps.setInt(1, onum);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                di = new DeliveryInfo();
                di.setOnum(rs.getInt("onum"));
                di.setCnum(rs.getInt("cnum"));
                di.setCname(rs.getString("cname"));
                di.setCaddress(rs.getString("caddress"));
                di.setQuant(rs.getInt("quant"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Search Fail");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            DBUtil.close(rs);
            DBUtil.close(ps);
            DBUtil.close(con);
        }
        return di;
    }
    public ArrayList<DeliveryInfo> deliverySearch(){
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        DeliveryInfo di = null;
        ArrayList<DeliveryInfo> deliveryInfoList = new ArrayList<>(); 
        String q = "Select onum, cnum, pnum, quant, cname, caddress"
                + " from OrderInfo o , Customer c"
                + " where o.onum = c.cnum and onum = ?";
        try {
            con = DBUtil.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(q);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                di = new DeliveryInfo(rs.getInt(1),rs.getInt(2),rs.getInt(3), rs.getInt(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6));
                deliveryInfoList.add(di);
            } // end of while

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Search Fail");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            DBUtil.close(rs);
            DBUtil.close(ps);
            DBUtil.close(con);
        }
        return deliveryInfoList;
    }
    public int getOrderPrice(int onum) {
        int tprice = 0;
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement preSt = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try {
            conn = DBUtil.getConnection();
            String query = "select quant, price from orderinfo, product "
                    + " where orderinfo.pnum=product.pnum and onum = ?";
            preSt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            preSt.setInt(1, onum);

            resultSet = preSt.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                int quant = resultSet.getInt("quant");
                int price = resultSet.getInt("price");
                tprice = quant * price;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            DBUtil.close(resultSet);
            DBUtil.close(preSt);
            DBUtil.close(conn);
        }
        return tprice;
    }// end of getOrderPrice
}
```

---

when I test this DAO out, I keep getting an error message that has something to do with the identifier...

I'm still new to Java and programming.. so I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: It would be most helpful if you posted the exact error message.

Comment: the error message somehow pops up in Korean on the console... weird eh? has something to do with the identifier...

Comment: What are you doing to "test this DAO out" and as Brian commented, the error message is essential to debug this (even if it is in Korean).

Answer (score 0):

```
first you should have created a table. Here's an example of creating a table.

    public class TableCreate {
    // Create Data (save) Create table
        public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
        SQLException {
            // 1. Create Driver (Object will be created automatically; register onto DriverManager
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            // 2. Create Connection
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE", "doll", "doll");
            // 3. Query, create Query performing object
            String q = "create table employee ( snum int primary key, "
                    + "sname varchar2(30), sdate varchar2(30), spart varchar2(20))";
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            // 4. Perform Query
            boolean rs = st.execute(q); //all - return: true - if ResultSet comes, then true/ false - if else
            //ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery (q); //Select
            //int rs = st.executeUpdate(q); //insert, update, delete
            // 5. Result Processing
            String q2 = "create sequence sseq";
            st.execute(q2);     
            // 6. Return Resource (close backwards)
            st.close();
            con.close();
        }
    }

***

Next, you will need these Utilities (Classes):

    public class DBUtil {

        static {
            // Create Driver
            try {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
            // Get Connection 
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE", "scsa", "scsa");
            return con;
        }

        public static void close(ResultSet rs) {
            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        public static void close(Statement ps) {
            if (ps != null)
                try {
                    ps.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        public static void close(Connection con) {
            if (con != null)
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }   //end of DBUtil

***

more utilities:

    public class DBUtil {

        static {
            // create Driver
            try {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
            // Connection creation
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE", "scsa", "scsa");
            return con;
        }

        public static void close(ResultSet rs) {
            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        public static void close(Statement ps) {
            if (ps != null)
                try {
                    ps.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        public static void close(Connection con) {
            if (con != null)
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }   //end of DBUtil

***
More Utilites

    public class RecordNotFoundException extends Exception {

        public RecordNotFoundException(){
            super("Such record does not exist.");
        }
    }

***
add fnct:

    public void add(OrderInfo o){
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            String q = "insert into OrderInfo values (oseq.nextval, ?, ?, ?)";

            try {
                con = DBUtil.getConnection();
                ps = con.prepareStatement(q);

                ps.setInt(1, o.getCnum());
                ps.setInt(2, o.getPnum());
                ps.setInt(3, o.getQuant());
                ps.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("Register Complete");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Register Fail");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                DBUtil.close(ps);
                DBUtil.close(con);
            }
        }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public void insertBook(Book book) throws DuplicateException {
            if (isbnExists(book.getIsbn())) {
                throw new DuplicateException();
            }

            Connection con = null;
            String q = "Insert into Book values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            try {
                con = DBUtil.getConnection();
                // Statement st = con.createStatement(); //Cannot recognize question marks. so don't use
                ps = con.prepareStatement(q);
                ps.setString(1, book.getIsbn());
                ps.setString(2, book.getTitle());
                ps.setString(3, book.getAuthor());
                ps.setInt(4, book.getPrice());
                ps.setString(5, book.getPublisher());
                ps.setString(6, book.getDescription());

                ps.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("1 Book Registration Complete");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to save data");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                DBUtil.close(ps);
                DBUtil.close(con);
            }
        }

***
ArrayList<Class> search() fnct:

    public ArrayList<Customer> search(){
            Connection con = null;
            Statement st = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            ArrayList<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<>();

            String q = "Select cnum, cname, caddress from Customer2";
            try{
                con = DBUtil.getConnection();
                st = con.createStatement();
                rs = st.executeQuery(q);
                while(rs.next()){
                    Customer customer = new Customer(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2),
                            rs.getString(3));
                    customerList.add(customer);
                } // end of while

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to search");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                DBUtil.close(rs);
                DBUtil.close(st);
                DBUtil.close(con);
            }
            return customerList;
        }
    }

***
ArrayList<subClass> subSearch() :

    public ArrayList<DeliveryInfo> deliverySearch(){
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            DeliveryInfo di = null;
            ArrayList<DeliveryInfo> deliveryInfoList = new ArrayList<>(); 
            String q = "Select onum, cnum, pnum, quant, cname, caddress"
                    + " from OrderInfo o , Customer c"
                    + " where o.onum = c.cnum and onum = ?";
            try {
                con = DBUtil.getConnection();
                ps = con.prepareStatement(q);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();

                while(rs.next()){
                    di = new DeliveryInfo(rs.getInt(1),rs.getInt(2),rs.getInt(3), rs.getInt(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6));
                    deliveryInfoList.add(di);
                } // end of while

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to Search");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                DBUtil.close(rs);
                DBUtil.close(ps);
                DBUtil.close(con);
            }
            return deliveryInfoList;
        }

***
public ArrayList<class> search(String name):

    public ArrayList<DeliveryInfo> deliverySearch(){
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            DeliveryInfo di = null;
            ArrayList<DeliveryInfo> deliveryInfoList = new ArrayList<>(); 
            String q = "Select onum, cnum, pnum, quant, cname, caddress"
                    + " from OrderInfo o , Customer c"
                    + " where o.onum = c.cnum and onum = ?";
            try {
                con = DBUtil.getConnection();
                ps = con.prepareStatement(q);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();

                while(rs.next()){
                    di = new DeliveryInfo(rs.getInt(1),rs.getInt(2),rs.getInt(3), rs.getInt(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6));
                    deliveryInfoList.add(di);
                } // end of while

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to search");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                DBUtil.close(rs);
                DBUtil.close(ps);
                DBUtil.close(con);
            }
            return deliveryInfoList;
        }

***

public className search(int num):

    public DeliveryInfo deliverySearch(int onum){
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            DeliveryInfo di = null;
            String q = "select onum, cnum, cname, caddress, quant "
                    + " from orderinfo o, customer c "
                    + " where o.onum = c.cnum and onum = ?";
            try {
                con = DBUtil.getConnection();
                ps = con.prepareStatement(q);
                ps.setInt(1, onum);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next()) {
                    di = new DeliveryInfo();
                    di.setOnum(rs.getInt("onum"));
                    di.setCnum(rs.getInt("cnum"));
                    di.setCname(rs.getString("cname"));
                    di.setCaddress(rs.getString("caddress"));
                    di.setQuant(rs.getInt("quant"));
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("failed to search");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                DBUtil.close(rs);
                DBUtil.close(ps);
                DBUtil.close(con);
            }
            return di;
        }

***

public int getOrderPrice(int num)

    public DeliveryInfo deliverySearch(int onum){
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            DeliveryInfo di = null;
            String q = "select onum, cnum, cname, caddress, quant "
                    + " from orderinfo o, customer c "
                    + " where o.onum = c.cnum and onum = ?";
            try {
                con = DBUtil.getConnection();
                ps = con.prepareStatement(q);
                ps.setInt(1, onum);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next()) {
                    di = new DeliveryInfo();
                    di.setOnum(rs.getInt("onum"));
                    di.setCnum(rs.getInt("cnum"));
                    di.setCname(rs.getString("cname"));
                    di.setCaddress(rs.getString("caddress"));
                    di.setQuant(rs.getInt("quant"));
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("failed to search");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                DBUtil.close(rs);
                DBUtil.close(ps);
                DBUtil.close(con);
            }
            return di;
        }

***

public void update(int anum, int balance)

    public void update(int anum, int balance) throws RecordNotFoundException {
    //      if (search(anum) == null) {
    //          throw new RecordNotFoundException();
    //      }
    //
    //      boolean result = false;
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            String q = "update Account set balance = ? where anum = ?";

            try {
                con = DBUtil.getConnection();
                ps = con.prepareStatement(q);
                ps.setInt(1, balance);
                ps.setInt(2, anum);

                ps.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("update fail");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                DBUtil.close(ps);
                DBUtil.close(con);
            }
        }

***
pub boolean update(int snum, String spart):

public boolean update(int snum, String spart) throws RecordNotFoundException {
        if(search(snum) == null){
            throw new RecordNotFoundException();
        }


        boolean result = false;
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        String q = "update Employee set spart = ? where snum = ?";

        try {
            con = DBUtil.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(q);
            ps.setString(1, spart);
            ps.setInt(2, snum);

            int re = ps.executeUpdate();
            if (re > 0) {
                result = true;
            }
            System.out.println("update success");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("update fail");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            DBUtil.close(ps);
            DBUtil.close(con);
        }
        return result;
    }

***
pub void update(Class c):

public void noticeUpdate(Notice n) throws RecordNotFoundException{
        if (!numExists(n.getNum())) {
            throw new RecordNotFoundException();
        }

        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        String q = "update Notice set  writer = ?,  title = ?, cont = ? where num = ?";

        try {
            con = DBUtil.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(q);
            ps.setString(1, n.getWriter());
            ps.setString(2, n.getTitle());
            ps.setString(3, n.getCont());
            ps.setInt(4, n.getNum());

            ps.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("update success");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("update fail");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            DBUtil.close(ps);
            DBUtil.close(con);
        }

    }

***
OrderTest{ :

public class OrderTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        OrderDAO adao = new OrderDAO();
//      adao.add(new OrderInfo(1,10,11000));
//      adao.add(new OrderInfo(2,11,220000));
//      adao.add(new OrderInfo(3,12,330000));
//      System.out.println(OrderDAO.search());
//      System.out.println(OrderDAO.search(1));
//      System.out.println(OrderDAO.getOrderPrice(2));


    }

    public static void displayAll(ArrayList<OrderInfo> list){
        System.out.println("============================");
        for(OrderInfo o : list){
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }
}

***
ProductTest{

    public class ProductTest {
    static ProductDAO dao;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
            dao = new ProductDAO();
    //      dao.add(new Product (10, "Galaxy Note 3", 140));
    //      dao.add(new Product (11, "Galaxy S4", 140));
    //      dao.add(new Product (12, "SmartTv", 7000));
            dao.add(new Product (14, "PS3", 7000, "Sony"));


    //      displayAll();

            ArrayList<Product> plist = dao.search();
            displayAll(plist);


        }

        public static void displayAll(ArrayList<Product> plist){
            System.out.println("=======Product List=======");
            for(Product p: plist){
                System.out.println(p);
            }
        }
    }

    ***

    Test w/ columnNames:

        public class EmployeeTest {
            static EmployeeDao dao;

            public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
                 dao = new EmployeeDao();
        //       dao.delete(6);
        //       dao.add("John", "RD");
        //       dao.add("Michael", "Development");
        //       dao.add("Hank", "Maintenance");
        //       dao.add("Andy", "Engineering");
        //       dao.add("Chris", "Global sales");
        //       dao.update(11, "Finance");

                 ArrayList<Employee> list = dao.search();
                 System.out.println(dao.getColumnNames());
                 displayAll(list);

            }


        public static void displayAll(ArrayList<Employee> list) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
            System.out.println("================== Employee List ==================");
            for(Employee emp : list){
                System.out.println(emp);
            }
        }

    }


***

pub CharSequence getColumnNames(){:

    public CharSequence getColumnNames() {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            String q = "Select * from employee";
            try {
                con = DBUtil.getConnection();
                ps = con.prepareStatement(q);

                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
                int count = md.getColumnCount();
                for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                    sb.append(md.getColumnName(i));
                    sb.append("  |  ");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Search Failed");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                DBUtil.close(rs);
                DBUtil.close(ps);
                DBUtil.close(con);
            }

            return sb;
        }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public String getHeader(){
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            String q = "Select * " + " from Notice";
            try {
                con = DBUtil.getConnection();
                ps = con.prepareStatement(q);

                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
                int count = md.getColumnCount();
                for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                    sb.append(md.getColumnName(i));
                    sb.append("  |  ");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("검색 실패");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                DBUtil.close(rs);
                DBUtil.close(ps);
                DBUtil.close(con);
            }

            return sb.toString();
        }




***
pub boolean delete (int snum):

    public boolean delete(int snum) {
            boolean result = false;
            // Product p = search(num);
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            String q = "delete from Employee where snum = ?";

            try {
                con = DBUtil.getConnection();
                ps = con.prepareStatement(q);
                ps.setInt(1, snum);

                int re = ps.executeUpdate();
                if (re > 0) {
                    result = true;
                }
                System.out.println("Delete Success");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Delete Fail");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                DBUtil.close(ps);
                DBUtil.close(con);
            }
            return result;

        }

***

pub void delete(int num) :

    public void delete(int num) {
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            String q = "delete from Product where num = ?";

            try {
                con = DBUtil.getConnection();
                ps = con.prepareStatement(q);
                ps.setInt(1, num);

                ps.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("Delete Success");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Delete Fail");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                DBUtil.close(ps);
                DBUtil.close(con);
            }

        }


***

tableCreate :

    public class TableCreate {
    // 데이터 생성 (저장) 테이블 생성
        public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
        SQLException {
            // 1. Create Driver 
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            // 2. Create Connection
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE", "scsa", "scsa");
            // 3. Query, create Query Performing Object 
            String q = "create table employee ( snum int primary key, "
                    + "sname varchar2(30), sdate varchar2(30), spart varchar2(20))";
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            // 4. Query Perform
            boolean rs = st.execute(q); //all - return: true - ResultSet== true/ false - else
            //ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery (q); //Select
            //int rs = st.executeUpdate(q); //insert, update, delete
            // 5. 결과처리
            String q2 = "create sequence sseq";
            st.execute(q2);     
    //      if (rs>0) {
    //          System.out.println("Delete Complete");
    //      }
            // 6. Return resources (backwards close)
            st.close();
            con.close();
        }
    }


***

    pub boolean numExist(int num) :

    public boolean numExists(int num){
            boolean flag = false;
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            String q = "Select num from Notice where num = ?";
            try {
                con = DBUtil.getConnection();
                ps = con.prepareStatement(q);

                ps.setInt(1, num);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next()) {
                    flag = true;
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Search Fail");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                DBUtil.close(rs);
                DBUtil.close(ps);
                DBUtil.close(con);
            }
            return flag;
        }
```

Comment: This isn't what OP asked for. I think OP has already created a table and `DBUtil` is an existing class that he used. So it's really what error info he got.